# Disk Management can't extend partition due to OEM partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have an SSD with a C drive of 56 GB and D drive of 53 GB. However, in Disk Management there is an OEM Partition between the two. I am not looking to remove the OEM Partition. I just wasn't able to  transfer 1 GB of space to D Drive.

However, even though I can shrink C drive, I cant Extend D Drive (it is greyed out)

It looks like this:

```
C          Unallocated       Oem      D
56.19GB        1GB           868MB    53.2GB
```

I want to extend the D drive. There is an unallocated space of 1 GiB. The extend volume button is greyed out.

Comment: You should be able to move the OEM partition down to abut with `C:`, so that the unallocated space becomes adjacent to `D:`, which you can then expand downwards. Alternatively, since 1GB is not going to make a huge difference to either drive, simply use it by expanding `C:`. You should be able to do this in standard Disc Management, but to do the more complex operation, you'll need non-native partitioning software. Whatever you do, you must back up first, preferably a full drive image.

Comment: Agree. We have to have your unallocated space right next to the partition you wish to extend, on the right side. There are many 3rd party partition managers out there, which should be able to extend the C: partition with the available unallocated space. backup any important data which you might have on that drive, before you edit the partitions, just in case anything unexpected happens.